# I want the following output using for loop in php

Tags: php

I want to display the output as like this

```
1        1
12      21
123    321
1234  4321
1234554321
```

Here is my php code

```
  for($i=1;$i <= 5;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {
    // print the result 
     echo "$j";


    }
    for($y=$i;$y<=$i;$y++)
    {
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    }
    for($k=$i;$k>=1;$k--)
     {

    // print the result 
      echo "&nbsp;$k";}

    echo "<br/>";
}
```

But I got the output like this

```
1   1
12   2 1
123   3 2 1
1234   4 3 2 1
12345   5 4 3 2 1
```

Please help me get an output like above.

Comment: I smell homework assignment or interview test

Comment: **Five** answers to this question. This is why we can't have nice things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
for($i=1;$i <= 5;$i++) {
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++) {
      echo "$j";
    }
    for($y=0;$y<(5-$i)*4;$y++) {
      echo '&nbsp;';
    }
    for($l=$i;$l>0;$l--) {
      echo "$l";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

output:-

```
1        1
12      21
123    321
1234  4321
1234554321
```

For browser view :- `for($y=0;$y<(5-$i)*4;$y++)` else correct way to going is `for($y=0;$y<(5-$i)*2;$y++)`

Comment: I think that you trying to view result in browswer. So there is some fonr issue. Correct your `($y=0;$y<(5-$i)*4;$y++)` to `($y=0;$y<(5-$i)*2;$y++)` and use monospace font.

Comment: @sectus yeah else it will be *2 let me mention it answer

Comment: If n value is 50 then spaces is diiferent. please help me

Comment: try for($y=0;$y<(50-$i)*2;$y++) for browser output for($y=0;$y<(50-$i)*4;$y++)

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever here about the PHP functions `str_repeat` and `range`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

With it you can print your `&nbsp;` character like this:

```
echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', (5 -$i) *4);
```

Complete code

```
$count = 5; // count oft rows and oft iterated numbers

for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    echo implode('', range(1, $i));
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', ($count -$i) *4);
    echo implode('', array_reverse(range(1, $i)));
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: That doesn't produce output In the required format. Although a solution using `str_pad` will surely be neat

Comment: Well why should I `read my(your) last sentence`? An answer is supposed to answer the question, not return apples when oranges were asked for. Yes `str_pad` is a good way to go but this solution doesn't even remotely output what the OP wants and you also overwrote my edit which fixed your syntax error :)

Comment: I hope now it's better. I'm sitting in a train, couldn't test my code, sorry

Comment: I've corrected my solution now. `str_pad` was not the right way, but `str_repeat`. It repeats the `&nbsp;` sign as specified in it's second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
   echo substr("12345", 0, $i);
   echo str_repeat(5-$i, '&nbsp;');
   echo str_reverse(substr("12345", 0, $i));
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  for($i=1;$i <= 5;$i++)
  {
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {
     echo "$j";
    }

    for($y=1;$y<=10-(2*$i);$y++)
    {
      echo '&nbsp;';
    }

    for($k=$i;$k>=1;$k--)
    {
     // print the result 
      echo "$k";
    }

    echo "<br/>";
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1        1
12      21
123    321
1234  4321
1234554321
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this with `$y<= 2 * (5 - i)`,

```
for($i=1;$i <= 5;$i++) {

    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++) {
       echo "$j";
    }

    for($y=1;$y<= 2 * (5 - i); $y++) {
       echo '&nbsp;';
    }

    for($k=$i;$k>=1;$k--) {
       echo "$k";
    }

   echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($counter=1;$counter<= 5;$conter++)
{
   for ($j=1;$j<=$counter;$j++)
   {
       echo "$j";
   }

   for ($y=1;$y<=10-(2*$counter);$y++)
   {
       echo '&nbsp;';
   }

   for ($k=$counter;$k>=1;$k--)
   {
       echo "$k";
   }
   echo "<br/>";
}
```